# MakeSignature.signDetached operation is taking too much time for few pdfs while sending requests on JBoss EAP through WebService

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, itext, jboss-eap-6

We are generating pdf with digital signature. this block of code is taking 10 to 15 secs randomly for few requests sent on JbossEAP using itextpdf 5.5.3

```
switch (digiSignDetails.getSigningMode()) {
            case 1:
                algorithm = "RIPEMD160";
                break;
            case 2:
                algorithm = "SHA1";
                break;
            case 3:
                algorithm = "SHA256";
                break;
            case 4:
                algorithm = "SHA384";
                break;
            case 5:
                algorithm = "SHA512";
                break;
            }
            ExternalSignature es = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, algorithm, "BC");
            ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, es, chain, null, null, null, 0, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Comment: The code you show does not in itself take so much time. There are some external factors you leave out. E.g. your `pk` private key: Does it reside on an external device which might introduce some delays? And I assume you did check and rule out that the "random" delays were related to large file sizes, didn't you?